# Disable "PIN required for additional security" prompt

Tags: root-access, security, lock-screens, xposed-framework

I have a Pixel 4a, and I constantly have to re-enter the pin, even though it hasn't been more than 48/72 hours. My Pixel 4a currently has a pretty bulky case, making it unreasonable that the fingerprint reader is being activated in my pocket, yet I still find myself frequently having to reenter my pin.

I'm looking for a simple clear-cut way to disable this. It's annoying, I think at times it could actually be *more* insecure, especially in places where there are cameras around capturing input.

My device is rooted, and I have xposed framework installed. How can I disable this abomination of a "security check"?

Comment: How often do you unlock your phone per day using fingerprint?

Comment: 2/3 times an hour. Sometimes more, depending on what I'm doing on my PC, if I need my phone for 2FA/Authy etc. I'd say in a given day, anywhere from 20-40 times.

Comment: [Closely related](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/241560) //what you want to do is not possible even with root /Xposed because you are dealing with TEE // using *lockdown* Option in power menu is the only way//BTW it's 72 hours not 48 hours

Comment: @beeshyams I restarted my phone no more than 4 hours ago (And unlocked with pin), and I was already prompted about 30 minutes ago to enter my pin again. Since my phone has been rebooted, my phone has been on a table, so idk why it's continuing to trigger this security check.

Comment: I have no idea why it happens with you. For me it was a custom kernel

Comment: Did you ever manage to find the solution to your issue ? I have exactly the same with my Fairphone 4 running LOS 19.1, after unlocking my device and putting it still on a table for 3 minutes, it will ask me for "pin for additional security".

Comment: @Marc Nope. It's extremely frustrating. Only thing I noticed, is that the original unlock (Even though it's requiring to use a pin), doesn't trigger the 72hr cooldown, so I'll always have to unlock it by pin twice before the 72hr cooldown triggers. This has to be a bug with TEE.

Comment: As a matter of fact I just resolved it a few minutes ago it appears by... resetting the PIN code. This is really weird. I assume you already tried that.

Comment: I'm sure it will be back, after a restart.

Comment: As a matter of fact it did not. So far so good. Really strange issue.