# How to disable (or configure) being prompted for password/PIN for "additional security"?

Tags: authentication

Android devices seem to generally require you to enter your PIN/password after successfully authenticating with your fingerprint.

The reasons for why this is happening and what triggers it are already layed out in [Conditions for triggering "pin required for additional security“](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/241560/conditions-for-triggering-pin-required-for-additional-security).

Now, with my old phone, this was annoying, with my new one this seems to happen with every second unlock. Hence, it needs to go. Really. Anyone here who knows how to

1. deactivate the feature altogether or
2. configure specific conditions for when it happens?