# Forgot PIN. Is there a way to reset PIN code with root and unlocked bootloader? OnePlus 7T

Tags: lock-screens, locked-out, oneplus

My phone is a OnePlus 7T with a root and unlocked bootloader. I was adding face unlocking and I've also set up a new PIN code. Everything was working great until the periodic prompt with the need to enter a PIN. Unfortunately, I don't remember it and I've got a big problem right now.

I don't know if it helps but my biometric unlocking methods should also work (fingerprint and face). I just need to pass that prompt for PIN and then reset it somehow. I've access to all Google accounts logged in the phone, but I don't see the option to reset the PIN code on https://www.google.com/android/find.

Is there a way to reset the PIN code somehow?

Comment: If you've not rebooted the device than make sure a reboot never happens or you would be locked out badly. Do you have USB debugging enabled and authorized? If yes for both, than get as much data from your device as much as you can using adb. You've to prepare yourself for a factory reset now. That's the final step unfortunately. Facial and fingerprint related data is not used for data encryption. It is either PIN/Password. Android at times (don't know why) require that the screen must be unlocked using PIN/Password, and that's where you are stuck now...

Comment: Once you've gotten hold of all the data you can get, see if this lockscreen bypass would work. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dSgSnYPgzT0 **Note carefully**: attempt this only after extracting data from your device or if you are simply unable to get data and you're left with nothing but a factory reset to do. If that hack works out, than your screen should be unlocked. In that case, it would be a bit more easy to get some more data cause the phone's UI would be accessible. But the original problem would still remain and the final step would still be a factory reset.

Comment: I don't remember if I had usb debugging enabled :(. If I'm trying to use adb I'm starting with adb devices command and it lists the device but it says that it is unauthorized.

Comment: Do you remember device is encrypted? for unencrypted device screen lock can reset from TWRP recovery

Comment: unfortunately it is :(

Comment: @Firelord, reason for Android asking PIN covered here https://android.stackexchange.com/q/241560/131553