# Samsung Galaxy A53 doesn't show fingerprint on lock screen when no app is running

Tags: samsung, lock-screens, fingerprint

I have a Samsung Galaxy A53 and I did a fingerprint on it. When there is no application opened and it enters the lock screen, I don't see the option to put my finger to open it, and I have to write down the PIN code that I chose.

[image]

But if I'm opening a certain application, it doesn't matter which one, WhatsApp or something, and the device goes to the lock screen through the button on the side, or if a minute passes, the fingerprint icon appears, and if I put my finger on it, it opens.

I searched in the settings and Google and didn't find anything about it.

Comment: It is more likely that you need to enter the PIN because the device has performed a reboot (and for that reason no app is running).

Comment: @Robert if an apps are running and im doing CLEAR ALL , and then im going to lockscreen the fingerprint its not showing up

Comment: Depending on circumstances, [Android may force the user to use PIN after several hours](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/241560/44325).